# how to merge two sorted arrays of same size?

Tags: java

1st array: `{3,5,6,9,12,14,18,20,25,28}`
2nd array: `{30,32,34,36,38,40,42,44,46,48}`

Sample Output:

```
{3,5,6,9,12,14,18,20,25,28,30,32,34,36,38,40,42,44,46,48}
```

I have to merge 1st array into second array. 2nd array has space to accomadate all values

Comment: Show us some code, what have you tried, where have you failed/got stuck etc.

Comment: In the sample output, where does the second closing brace come from? And the spaces?

Answer (score 1):

Use System.arraycopy to append a1 to a2

```
System.arraycopy(a1, 0, a2, a2_len, a1.length);
```

then Arrays.sort

Comment: As the name suggested, `System.arraycopy` merely copies. It doesn't resize and this will throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: Question says  2nd array has space to accomadate all values

Comment: Just noticed that. Very very very weird merge sort implementation. If this is even merge sort.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever i know i need a collection to be sorted, i use a method that will insert new elements in right place, so the collection will never have state when its not sorted... in your case you might be good with adding two into destination collection then use `Collections.sort()` but you can do `sortedInsert()` as well... you can create your collection and start addin all items into it using this method, and when you finished you dont need another call to `Collections.sort()` because collection is always in sorted state... This is handy if you often do single element update and dont want whole collection to be resorted... this will work with much better performance...

Here is what i do for List

```
/**
   * Inserts the value keeping collection sorted, provided collections shall be sorted with provided
   * comparator
   */
  public static <E> void sortedInsert(List<E> list, E value, Comparator<? super E> comparator) {
    assert Ordering.from(comparator).isOrdered(list);

    if (list.size() == 0) {
      list.add(value);
    } else if (comparator.compare(list.get(0), value) > 0) {
      list.add(0, value);
    } else if (comparator.compare(list.get(list.size() - 1), value) < 0) {
      list.add(list.size(), value);
    } else {
      int i = 0;
      while (comparator.compare(list.get(i), value) < 0) {
        i++;
      }
      list.add(i, value);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a `ArrayList` object as `arrayListObject`

```
ArrayList<Integer> arrayListObject= new ArrayList<>();
```

Add elements of both arrays in that `arrayListObject`

Do `Collectios.sort(arrayListObject)` to sort the elements.

Use

```
Integer list2[] = new Integer[arrayListObject.size()];
        list2 =  arrayListObject.toArray(list2);
```

to get the resulted array

Comment: `(Integer[]) arrayListObject.toArray();` will throw an exception. You need to use [the other overload](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray-T:A-) `<T> T[] toArray(T[])`.

Answer (score 0):

Use two pointers/counters, `i` & `j` starting from 0 to size of the array. Compare `a[i]` & `b[j]` and based on the result shift `i` or `j` (similar to merge sort, merging step). If extra space isn't allowed then in worst case (which is true in your input, all the elements in first array is smaller than first element in second array) you might have to shift 2nd array every time you compare elements.